# How to calculate the maximum number of overlapping intervals in R?

Tags: r, intervals

I have a dataset with the variables of `start_date`and `end_date`. And I use them to create a variable called `interval_date` to capture the range between them. Eventually, I need to calculate the maximum number of overlapping intervals.

Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
library(lubridate)

member_id <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 2))
start_date <- ymd(c("2018-10-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-10-25", "2021-06-01", 
                    "2010-05-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-02-01", 
                    "2021-02-01", "2021-04-21"))

end_date <- ymd(c("2021-04-30", "2022-08-08", "2022-08-08", "2022-08-08", 
                  "2022-08-08", "2022-08-08", "2022-08-08", 
                  "2021-04-30", "2022-08-08"))

interval_date <- interval(start_date, end_date)

df <- data.frame(member_id, start_date, end_date, interval_date)
```

The dataset looks like this:

```
  member_id start_date   end_date                  interval_date
1         1 2018-10-01 2021-04-30 2018-10-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC
2         1 2019-12-01 2022-08-08 2019-12-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC
3         1 2020-10-25 2022-08-08 2020-10-25 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC
4         1 2021-06-01 2022-08-08 2021-06-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC
5         2 2010-05-01 2022-08-08 2010-05-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC
6         2 2020-01-01 2022-08-08 2020-01-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC
7         2 2021-02-01 2022-08-08 2021-02-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC
8         3 2021-02-01 2021-04-30 2021-02-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC
9         3 2021-04-21 2022-08-08 2021-04-21 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC
```

And I need to calculate the maximum number of overlapping intervals for each member (group by `member_id`).

**The final output should look like this:**

```
  member_id start_date   end_date                  interval_date max_overlap
1         1 2018-10-01 2021-04-30 2018-10-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC           3
2         1 2019-12-01 2022-08-08 2019-12-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
3         1 2020-10-25 2022-08-08 2020-10-25 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
4         1 2021-06-01 2022-08-08 2021-06-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
5         2 2010-05-01 2022-08-08 2010-05-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
6         2 2020-01-01 2022-08-08 2020-01-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
7         2 2021-02-01 2022-08-08 2021-02-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
8         3 2021-02-01 2021-04-30 2021-02-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC           2
9         3 2021-04-21 2022-08-08 2021-04-21 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           2
```

I get inspired by the answer from this post ([Count how many times date ranges overlap for each category (machine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536298/count-how-many-times-date-ranges-overlap-for-each-category-machine)) and adapt the code like this:

```
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_by(member_id) %>%
  mutate(numb_times_with_overlap = imap_int(interval_date,
                                            ~sum(int_overlaps(.x, interval_date)) - 1L))
```

But it is counting the number of overlapping intervals **between one interval and other intervals**, but I need the maximum number of overlapping intervals **among all the intervals** within the group.

```
  member_id start_date end_date   interval_date                  numb_times_with_overlap
      <dbl> <date>     <date>     <Interval>                                       <int>
1         1 2018-10-01 2021-04-30 2018-10-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC                       2
2         1 2019-12-01 2022-08-08 2019-12-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC                       3
3         1 2020-10-25 2022-08-08 2020-10-25 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC                       3
4         1 2021-06-01 2022-08-08 2021-06-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC                       2
5         2 2010-05-01 2022-08-08 2010-05-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC                       2
6         2 2020-01-01 2022-08-08 2020-01-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC                       2
7         2 2021-02-01 2022-08-08 2021-02-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC                       2
8         3 2021-02-01 2021-04-30 2021-02-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC                       1
9         3 2021-04-21 2022-08-08 2021-04-21 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC                       1
```

This article (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-number-of-overlapping-intervals/) describes the exact task I want to conduct and offers a solution. I am wondering how this can be translated into R. Or there are any other approaches to address this problem?

Comment: Why should member_id 3 have a max_overlap of 2 and not 1?

Comment: Maybe I can give some context to explain this. Imagine each row represents one contract with the start and end date, when there is 1 overlap, it means there are 2 contracts overlapping with each other. I want to capture the number of 2 here because I want to know the maximum amount of contracts an individual can hold during the overlapping period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

There might be a more efficient solution, but this should work.

For each member_id, traverse through all dates from `min(start_date)` to `max(end_date)` and count the number of contracts on each day. Return the maximum value.

```
df %>%
  split(member_id) %>%
  map_dfr(\(x) mutate(x, max_overlap = max(map_int(seq(min(start_date), max(end_date), 1),
                                                   \(d) sum(d %within% x$interval_date)))))

#>   member_id start_date   end_date                  interval_date max_overlap
#> 1         1 2018-10-01 2021-04-30 2018-10-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC           3
#> 2         1 2019-12-01 2022-08-08 2019-12-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
#> 3         1 2020-10-25 2022-08-08 2020-10-25 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
#> 4         1 2021-06-01 2022-08-08 2021-06-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
#> 5         2 2010-05-01 2022-08-08 2010-05-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
#> 6         2 2020-01-01 2022-08-08 2020-01-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
#> 7         2 2021-02-01 2022-08-08 2021-02-01 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           3
#> 8         3 2021-02-01 2021-04-30 2021-02-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC           2
#> 9         3 2021-04-21 2022-08-08 2021-04-21 UTC--2022-08-08 UTC           2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the goal here is not to calculate the maximum number of overlapping intervals between one row and the rest, but to **calculate the maximum number of overlapping intervals among all the intervals**. 

For example, A can overlap with B and C. So A overlaps twice. Meanwhile, B overlaps with C as well. So the maximum number of overlapping intervals should be 3, not 2. If I wrap `max` around the `imap_int`, I will get the number of 2.

Comment: @Sue See the edit above

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! But I make a small change. I am not sure why `split()` doesn't work in my bigger dataset. So I change it to `group_split()`. Hope it serves the same purpose. Thanks again for your help! Really appreciate it!